# Domino 8.5.2 mobile controls

Tags: dojo, xpages, xpages-extlib

I have installed domino designer 8.5.2 with extension library and dojo 1.4.3.
I have written coding in source of the Xpage is given by,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
<xe:mApp id="mApp1" selectedPageId="home">
    <xe:mPage id="home" loaded="true" preload="true"
        resetContent="false">
        <xe:djxmHeading id="djxmHeading1" label="Testing">
        </xe:djxmHeading>
    </xe:mPage>
</xe:mApp>
</xp:view>
```

when previewing in the  browser, it showing error as,

**"NetworkError: 404 Not Found -"
TabBar.js
failed loading /xsp/.ibmxspres/.extlib/dijit/Mobile.js with error: Error: Could not load 'dojox.mobile.TabBar'; last tried '../dojox/mobile/TabBar.js'

...x=d._toPixelValue;var astr="DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha";var af=function(n,...**

what could be the reason, i have installed dojo in server also...please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you installed Extension Library on the server too?

Comment: yes i have installed Extension library on the server also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dojo 1.4.3 doesn't support mobile controls. These were introduced in Dojo 1.5.1. So if you want to use the mobile controls, you will need to use the mobile controls project on OpenNTF.
Inside is some infrastructure who will detect the server version of Dojo. If it is below 1.5.1 it will use it's version, who is inside the database.
Latest version can be found here, http://mobilecontrols.openntf.org/
It is not well maintained lately.